# Как запретить повторное отображение пароля в EditTextPreference

Tags: android

Всем привет!
Есть активити с настройками. Там для ввода пароля использую `EditTextPreference`:

```
 <EditTextPreference
    android:key="pr_pwd"
    android:title="Пароль"
    android:summary="для входа в программу" 
    android:defaultValue=""
    android:dialogTitle="Укажите пароль"
    android:inputType="textPassword" 
 android:maxLines="1"/>
```

Интересует, как сделать так, чтобы при повторном вводе пароля (если, например, пользователь захотел его сменить), в окне ввода ничего не отображалось? На данный момент отображается введенный ранее пароль, замаскированный точками. А надо даже чтобы кол-во символов в пароле узнать нельзя было.

Подскажите, можно ли это указать в настройках `EditTextPreference` или же надо перехватывать какое-то событие, чтобы вручную затереть поле ввода?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Заведите в `onCreate()`

```
EditTextPreference editTextPreferenc=(EditTextPreference )findPreference("pr_pwd");
editTextPreference.setText("");
```

Comment: Спасибо.
Одно уточнение - в OnCreate самой Activity?

Comment: тут Bamaley попросил оценить полезность :)
оцениваю - БЕСПОЛЕЗНО :)

Comment: я таки сделал по-своему. свой диалог ввода пароля, который выскакивает при выборе соответствующего пунка в настройках приложения ну и т.д. сам сделал, сам верчу как хочу :)